# java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, sqlite

Below is my code for accessing the database and I am getting the following error:

> org.json.JSONException: Value

```
       public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            tim = time.getText().toString();
            na = name.getText().toString();
            da = date.getText().toString();

            insert();
        }
    });
}}

public void insert()
{
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("time",tim));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",na));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date",da));

    try
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/mts.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
        Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                (new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
        Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
    }

    try
    {
        JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
        code=(json_data.getInt("code"));

        if(code==1)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Inserted Successfully",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sorry, Try Again",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
    }
}
```

This the php code
Errors are:

> Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO

and

> Warning: mysql_connect() line 7

```
<?php
    $host='127.0.0.1';
    $uname='root';
    $pwd='password';
    $db="android";

enter code here

$con = MySQLi($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("connection failed");
    mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die("db selection failed");

    $id=$_REQUEST['time'];
    $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
    $date=$_REQUEST['date'];

    $flag['code']=0;

    if($r=mysql_query("insert into sample values('$time','$name',$'date') ",$con))
    {
        $flag['code']=1;
        echo"";
    }

    print(json_encode($flag));
    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

**logcat**

> 548-548/com.example.gurucharan.mts D/dalvikvm﹕ Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
>   548-548/com.example.gurucharan.mts D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 123K, 3% free 9218K/9415K, paused 60ms
>   548-548/com.example.gurucharan.mts I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 12.827MB for 3940072-byte allocation
>   548-554/com.example.gurucharan.mts I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
>   548-551/com.example.gurucharan.mts D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 2% free 13065K/13319K, paused 5ms+16ms
>   548-554/com.example.gurucharan.mts I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
>   548-554/com.example.gurucharan.mts I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
>   548-554/com.example.gurucharan.mts I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
>   548-554/com.example.gurucharan.mts I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
>   548-554/com.example.gurucharan.mts I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
>   548-554/com.example.gurucharan.mts I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
>   548-554/com.example.gurucharan.mts I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
>   548-548/com.example.gurucharan.mts D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
>   548-548/com.example.gurucharan.mts D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
>   548-548/com.example.gurucharan.mts D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xd77e8, tid 548
>   548-548/com.example.gurucharan.mts D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
>   548-548/com.example.gurucharan.mts D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
>   548-554/com.example.gurucharan.mts I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
>   548-554/com.example.gurucharan.mts I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
>   548-548/com.example.gurucharan.mts W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
>   548-548/com.example.gurucharan.mts D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
>   548-554/com.example.gurucharan.mts I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
>   548-554/com.example.gurucharan.mts I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
>   548-554/com.example.gurucharan.mts I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
>   548-554/com.example.gurucharan.mts I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
>   548-554/com.example.gurucharan.mts I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
>   548-554/com.example.gurucharan.mts I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
>   548-554/com.example.gurucharan.mts I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
>   548-554/com.example.gurucharan.mts I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
>   548-554/com.example.gurucharan.mts I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
>   548-554/com.example.gurucharan.mts I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
>   548-548/com.example.gurucharan.mts E/pass 1﹕ connection success
>   548-548/com.example.gurucharan.mts E/pass 2﹕ connection success
>   548-548/com.example.gurucharan.mts E/Fail 3﹕ org.json.JSONException: Value

Comment: please put the whole logcat so that we can see the type of error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See how i am using php coding for insertion

```
<?php
$host="host"; //replace with database hostname
$username="example"; //replace with database username
$password="examplepass"; //replace with database password
$db_name="empinfo"; //replace with database name
 // i used mysql_connect
$con = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die("connection failed");
mysql_select_db($db_name,$con) or die("db selection failed");

if(isset($_REQUEST)){
$topic=$_REQUEST['topic'];
$text=$_REQUEST['picname'];
$aid=$_REQUEST['aid'];
$date=$_REQUEST['date'];}

$texttt = "Picture";
$flag['code']=0;
$last_ID = 0;
$adminpic = "ASd";

// also mentioned the fields value of table in insert query

if($r=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `UPicture` (`ID` ,`AID` ,`ImageName` ,`Topic` ,`Date` ) VALUES (NULL, '$aid', '$text', '$topic', '$date'); ",$con))
{
$flag['code']=1;
$last_ID = mysql_insert_id();
}

$r=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `front_list` (`ID` ,`AID` ,`posttype` ,`date` ,`MID` ,`Adminpic`)VALUES (NULL , '$aid', '$texttt', '$date', '$last_ID', '$adminpic'); ",$con);

echo(json_encode($flag));
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

NOTE:

for new version of php add this line after `<?php` snippet

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
```